# Tkinter text not showing as supposed to

Tags: python, tkinter, request, python-requests

Recently I decided to play a little bit with tkinter , and I wanted to get the headers from a website and put them in a tkinter window

I managed to take the headers but , when i run the code , the data is messed up and hard to read . Does anyone have any idea how can i make it readable ? Thanks!

main.py

```
from tkinter import *
from alx_tk import * 

window = Tk()

window.title("Welcome to LikeGeeks app")

window.geometry('1920x1080')

txt = Entry(window,width=10)

txt.grid(column=0, row=0)

lbl = Label(window, text="Response")

lbl.grid(column=0, row=1)



hd = Label(window, text="Headers")

hd.grid(column=0, row=2)

header_ = Label(window, text="Results")
header_.grid(column=0, row=3)

def clicked():

   # res = "Welcome to " + txt.get()
    resp = get_req(txt.get())
    lbl.configure(text= resp)
   # lbl.configure(text= res)
def header():
    rss = headerss(txt.get())
    header_.configure(text= rss)    
btn = Button(window, text="Start", command=clicked)

btn.grid(column=2, row=1)
hdbutton = Button(window, text="Start", command= header)
hdbutton.grid(column=2, row=2)
window.mainloop()
```

alx_tk.py

```
import requests

def get_req(target):
    resp = requests.get(target)
    return resp

def headerss(target):
    test =  []
    resp = requests.get(target)
    for key ,value in resp.headers.items():
        a = key + value
        test.append(a)
    return test
```

Thanks, again!

Comment: What does "messed up and hard to read" mean? How is it messed up?

Comment: Wait i will give you a screen shot on imgur

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/LY38eFa

Comment: @BryanOakley ^^

Comment: if you want you can run it by : python2 main.tk , at the top add https://www.google.com and click the button next to the header

Comment: That picture doesn't tell us anything. It shows a very long text string in a tiny font. Of course that's going to be hard to read. What do you want to do instead of what it's doing? Are you expecting it to wrap? Have a bigger font? Newlines after each header? Something else?

Comment: @BryanOakley i want them to look like a normal request : https://imgur.com/a/vzBPDSC

Comment: This hasn't much todo with tkinter. You need to format your request then. Google tells me this could help https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.text

Comment: Yeah ,i think that too

Comment: How do i add an comment as solution @Atlas435 =)

Comment: I didnt solved anything. I would suggest to rewrite your Question and add the right tags to it, so the cummunity can help you out.

Comment: or you could delete the post and ask a new Q

Comment: @Atlas435: it is partly related to tkinter. They are displaying a list in a label, and tkinter will add curly braces to the data because it's a list rather than a string. Though, that's only part of the problem.

Comment: Seem like I was wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to want to generate multiple lines of output. A label is a poor choice. While you can use a label, it will likely require more work and yield a weaker user experience then using a text widget.

A text widget has wrapping built-in, so it will be easier to get the long cookie to wrap. A text widget also supports scrolling, which a label does not. A text widget also supports being able to select and copy the text.

So, let's start by changing your label to a text widget:

```
header_ = Text(window)
header_.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=3)
```

Next, you want a tab or a space between the key and value:

```
for key , value in resp.headers.items():
    a = f"{key}\t{value}"
    test.append(a)
```

Finally, convert the list to a string of values separated by newlines and then add this string to the text widget using `insert`:

```
def header():
    headers = headerss(txt.get())
    rss = "\n".join(headers)
    header_.delete("1.0", "end")
    header_.insert("end", rss)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: i get this error tho :     a = f"{key}\t{value}"
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax